# Eclipse: Error (Bytecode Outline) SOURCE FILE [in PROJECT] is not on its project's build path

Tags: eclipse, java-bytecode-asm

I've just installer the ASM Eclipse Plugin (and restarted), which give an improved Bytecode Outline, and I can use it for the JRE classes, but looking at my own code, I get the error message in the title.

My java project is on Build Automatically, and I my source files do not have errors, and I can see the class files in the Default output folder defined in the Java Build Path of the Project's properties.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it showing such a problem?
"Error (Bytecode Outline) src/Foo.java [in BarProject] is not on its project's build path.
"
That's a version problem.
Use http://andrei.gmxhome.de/eclipse/ as the update URL with the update manager and install the new version.

[this can help you](http://abhisanoujam.blogspot.com/2008/10/asm-eclipse-plugin-ganymede-not-on-its.html)